# How do I create a cool looking photo gallery

Tags: asp.net

How can I achieve a cool looking photo gallery page?  I don't know Flash, but can learn, and thought about a random collage that 'pulls out' a photo that you hover over.

It's for a photographer, so no thumbnails, grids, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a tool that's pretty flexible and will support itself later on as you can just train the user to work with it check out [JAlbum](http://jalbum.net/).

To work on integrating this yourself you can check out [AJAX ASP Photo Gallery](http://www.aspphotogallery.net/) or something like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/Nileblitz_Photo_Gallery.aspx).

If you're looking for a flash/flex based solution that they can just "plug-in" as a stand-alone product which incorporates some of the features you've described [StudioCloud](http://studiocloud.com/OnlineGallery.html) has a nice one that has a monthly fee...

Answer (score 2):

I have had good results using the Galleria plugin for jQuery: http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/.

It will require an html page as a source, but this is relatively easy to produce automatically from a database or directory structure using ASP.NET

If the data does not need to be updated too often you could even produce the HTML by hand in a pinch. It wouldnt be difficult though it isnt easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mat - [JAlbum](http://jalbum.net/) is excellent - but I'd also like to add that it's even better with the [BananAlbum](http://www.bananalbum.com/) skin.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of off the shelf apps available. Gallery, Wordpress (after configuration), and a few ASP.Net based ones. Flash is certainly not required.

That said, in order to learn a bit about Pylons, I wrote my own [basic photo blog](http://photo.krazyyak.com). If you can do basic CRUD development, it shouldn't be too hard.

Regarding your collage idea, you can accomplish that with JavaScript as well. See this [article](http://nettuts.com/javascript-ajax/leopard-desktop-in-jquery-using-jqdock/) for similar effects stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A little random, but the Silverlight deep zoom functionality is pretty cool around this area (although whether it's worth learning for this is another matter):

Example here: http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/